# GreenDao query OR within AND

Tags: greendao

I would like to build the following query using GreenDao.

```
select * from luckydrawclick e where e.user = ? and (e.id = ? or e.id = ? or e.id = ? or e.id = ? or e.id = ?);
```

The following is what I have so far.

```
List<LuckyDrawClick> luckyDrawClicks = luckyDrawClickDao.queryBuilder().where(Properties.User.eq(currentUser)).and(**********).list();
```

What do I need to place where `**********` is?

Answer (score 6):

I have found the answer to my own question.

```
QueryBuilder<LuckyDrawClick> qb = luckyDrawClickDao.queryBuilder();     
qb.where(Properties.Id.in(ids), Properties.User.eq(currentUser));
List<LuckyDrawClick> luckyDrawClicks = qb.list();
```

Comment: Thank you! It's a good idea to change "qb.and()" with "qb.where(Condition1, Conditions2, ...) and change "qb.or()" with "qb.whereOr(C1, C2, ...)"

Comment: @Sergio He doesn't use or conditions he uses in expression (which seems a pretty good solution to me).

Answer (score 6):

`QueryBuilder.and()` and `QueryBuilder.or()` are used to combine `WhereCondition`s.
The resulting `WhereCondition`s have to be used inside `QueryBuilder.where()` (which will combine the conditions using `AND`) or `QueryBuilder.whereOr()`.

Comment: This doesn't help to understand the following java-doc: QueryBuilder.and() Creates a WhereCondition by combining the given conditions using AND. The returned WhereCondition must be used inside where(WhereCondition, WhereCondition...) or whereOr(WhereCondition, WhereCondition, WhereCondition...).

Comment: @Sergio I don't understand your comment. My post is nearly the same as your cited doc. Do you mean I should have posted a more specific code example?